# CSS : easy way to apply _blank to multiple links?

Tags: html, css

each day im adding around 50 links + to an intranet page , is there an easy way of adding the _blank attribute - by using CSS instead of applying it to EVERY.SINGLE link I put in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use JavaScript for this](http://www.sitepoint.com/standards-compliant-world/):

```
function externalLinks() { 
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return; 
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
    for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) { 
        var anchor = anchors[i]; 
        if (anchor.getAttribute("href"))      
            anchor.target = "_blank"; 
    }  
} 
window.onload = externalLinks;
```

Comment: Thankyou! can I just add this to the header or do I need a javascript page for it?

Comment: You can do it either way. I just updated the code so make sure you have the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

No. `_blank` has nothing to do with CSS. There is an easy way using Javascript though.